# I want to send numerous udp messages by udp client,how could I achieve it?

Tags: reactor-netty

I want to send numerous udp messages by udp client at once ,but the demo only send one message.how could i achieve it?

With the demo code,I can only send a finite number of messages.I want to use a while(true) to send message ,how could i achieve it?

public static void main(String[] args) {
        Connection connection =
                UdpClient.create()
                        .host("localhost")
                        .port(8080)
                        .handle((udpInbound, udpOutbound) -> {
                             return udpOutbound.sendString(Mono.just("end")).sendString(Mono.just("end1")).sendString(Mono.just("end2"));
                        })
                        .connectNow(Duration.ofSeconds(30));
       connection.onDispose()
                .block();
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Flux` instead of `Mono` when you want to send more than one message.
One `sendString(Flux)`invocation is better in comparison with the approach with many `sendString(Mono)` invocations.
The example below uses `Flux.interval` so that you have infinite stream that emits messages every 100ms. Also when you have an infinite stream you have to switch to [flush on each strategy](http://next.projectreactor.io/docs/netty/snapshot/reference/index.html#_flushing_strategies_6)

```
Connection connection =
        UdpClient.create()
                 .host("localhost")
                 .port(8080)
                 .handle((udpInbound, udpOutbound) ->
                         udpOutbound.options(NettyPipeline.SendOptions::flushOnEach)
                                    .sendString(Flux.interval(Duration.ofMillis(100))
                                                    .map(l -> l + "")))
                 .connectNow(Duration.ofSeconds(30));
```